# Can I add custom Message-ID and In-Reply-To header using phpmailer?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, email-headers

I am using [phpmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) for sending emails, I am attempting to add `In-Reply-To` in email header but I can't. How can I achieve this? Can I use any `message-ID` or references when I am sending a email? Is there anything else to add `references` or `In-Reply-To` in phpmailer?

So far I have tried to add below line in phpmailer

```
$mail->AddCustomHeader("In-Reply-To: ")
```

but it's not working. I also tried to change the return path code like

```
$mail->ReturnPath = 'bounce_here@domain.com';
```

but it did not change the return path as well.

And one more things, Can I get the `message id` by using `imap` php?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can fetch the message over IMAP, then extract the headers using [imap_headerinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-headerinfo.php).

Once you've got the original message ID, you can insert it into your new message.

You need to provide a value to `addCustomHeader`, not just a name, [as the documentation says](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#method_addCustomHeader), like this:

```
$mail->addCustomHeader('In-Reply-To', $headerinfo['message_id']);
```

Don't set the return path yourself - that's the job of the message receiver. What you need to set is the `Sender` property:

```
$mail->Sender = 'bounce_here@domain.com';
```